# Cron tab and schedule: is it needed for layout compile/custom modules?

Tags: magento2, module, cron, crontab, magento-cron

My current store's staging instance does not have crontab set up as far as I can tell. The cron_schedule table is empty. Is this needed for custom modules/themes/etc to work properly?

What is the most basic setup I can do in order to get the above to work if needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, what you have set on your store.
Please refer to this guide.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html